# org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for octave!

Tags: org-mode, octave

I tried to execute an org-mode code block in octave, using the example in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742075):

```
#+name: factor
#+begin_src octave :session *octave* :exports code :results silent
factor=4;
#+end_src
```

But I got an error:

```
org-babel-execute-src-block: No org-babel-execute function for octave!
```

I have enabled org-babel for matlab and ocatve in emacs init file as far as I can. Emacs seems to recognize `.m` files when loaded (The buffer is recognized as a `Octave` buffer).

*Am I missing something in configuring org-mode for octave?*

By the way, this is with the default Emacs 26 from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. And my org-babel configuration is:

```lisp
(org-babel-do-load-languages
  'org-babel-load-languages
    '((emacs-lisp . t)
       ...
       (octave . t)
       (matlab . t)
       ))
```

and I also have this for octave mode in my init file:

```lisp
;; (autoload 'octave-mode "octave-mod" nil t) ;;outdated
(setq auto-mode-alist
  (cons '("\\.m$" . octave-mode) auto-mode-alist))

(add-hook 'octave-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (abbrev-mode 1)
            (auto-fill-mode 1)
            (if (eq window-system 'x)
                (font-lock-mode 1))))
```

Comment: That should be enough. What happens if you say `M-x load-library RET ob-octave RET`?

Comment: @NickD Thanks. that seems to work: `Loading ob-octave...done` after `M-x load-library RET ob-octave RET`, and `executing Octave code block (factor)...` after `C-c C-c`. Is there a way to `load-library` in emacs init.el?

Comment: The `org-babel-do-load-languages` call should have done that: you should investigate why it is not effective. Do you get any messages in the *Messages* buffer when it is evaluated?

Comment: Also check the value of `org-babel-load-languages` with `C-h v org-babel-load-languages   RET` (in a fresh invocation of emacs) and see if `octave` is included. Also check the value of `load-path` to make sure that emacs can find everything it needs to load.

Comment: @NickD Thanks. It seems that the problem is solved after I restart emacs. I guess it happened somewhere before I added the last configuration in the question.