# How do octave functions work in org-mode code blocks?

Tags: org-mode, octave

I tried to define and use a simple matlab/octave function within an org-mode code block as shown follows.

```
#+name: test-octave-function
#+begin_src octave
  function s = my_sum(x, y)
  s = x + y;
  end

  my_sum(1, 2)
#+end_src
```

The code works if put inside a `.m` file. However, in a code-block, it generates this error in Org-babel output:

> warning: function name 'my_sum' does not agree with function filename
>   ''
>
> error: 'my_sum' undefined near line 1 column 1

I understand functions defined for use in other files need to have the same name as the .m file. But how do filenames work for a code block. Also, I called the function `my_sum` in the same code block, why is it undefined?

*Related to this, how can I define and use multiple functions in a code block?*

(This is with the stock Emacs 26 of Ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: Please try to ask only one question per question. You've asked at least 3 here. Consider posting separate questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get the same result as you do and I'm not sure how it is supposed to work (I suspect bugs but I have not investigated).

However, it does work better in a session:

```
#+name: test-octave-function
#+begin_src octave :session foo
function retval = mysum(x, y)
  retval = x + y;
end

ans = mysum(5, 12)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS: test-octave-function
: 17
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this, but the `No org-babel-execute function for octave` issue (https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/58856) came back after adding `:session`. `load-library` on `ob-octave` doesn't fix it this time. After removing `:session`, the code block can be evaluated, but the `function undefined` problem here came back.

Comment: I removed my `elpa` folder, and re-initiated all packages, and now it seems to work (so far).